# Зациклить увеличение\уменьшение (моргание в ввиде увеличение\уменьшение)

Tags: jquery

```
function increase() {
$('#logo_heart').animate({
  'width': '410px',
  'marginLeft': '-20px',
  'marginTop': '-20px',
}, 500);
}

function reduce() {
$('#logo_heart').animate({
  'width': '348px',
  'marginLeft': '20px',
  'marginTop': '20px',
}, 500);

}

$('#logo_heart').hover(increase, reduce);
```

Не могу сделать что бы при наведении были зациклены 2 функции увеличение и уменьшение а если мышку убрали с элемента то становится в уменьшение объект.

Comment: А **setInterval()** разве не помогает? По наведению запускаете цикл, где отрабатывают ваши функции (**reduce** - в callback-е первой), а когда курсор убрали - **clearInterval(ID)** и одна функция, та что **reduce**.

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, то добавьте перед анимацией метод `stop()`:

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/W42dC/

```
$logo_heart = $('#logo_heart');

function increase() {
    $logo_heart.stop().animate({
      'width': '410px',
      'marginLeft': '-20px',
      'marginTop': '-20px',
    }, 500);
}

function reduce() {
    $logo_heart.stop().animate({
      'width': '348px',
      'marginLeft': '20px',
      'marginTop': '20px',
    }, 500);
}

$logo_heart.hover(increase, reduce);
```

Comment: мне казалось, что надо [так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/W42dC/1/)

Comment: правильно показалось, все верно что бы пульсировало! спасибо! PS: коментом ВМР скину на чипсы.